# Blackberry with Android OS6.0.1

Tags: xamarin.forms, blackberry

We have developed an android/ios app using xamarin forms.  The app is running on samsung, sony,iphone6s and iphone 8+ successfully.  But when i tried the same app in  Blackberry Priv (STV100-4) running on Android 6.0.1 the app is crashed when we tried to login.  Login in an Get methodl used to authenticate the user. Does xamarin apps suport Blackberry devices with android OS or not.

Comment: I really don't believe that XF are device dependent, Can you give more info about your crash? Error Message, Call stack, etc

Comment: We are not having the device to analyse the logs.  Will share the logs once we included the crash analytics and provide the build.Error message is "Unfortunately the app is closed"